# Frequency of translation updates from Transifex

Tags: support, bug, localization, transifex

I would like to know how often translations from transifex.com get loaded into the SE engine. In particular, according to information from Transifex, [the description for spoilers](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/298791300?q=key%3A2fb3669c0b86a73b5bec1f36d0d249fe) was updated 5 days ago:

> [image: transifex]

but [the translation doesn’t show up](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#spoilers) on Stack Overflow in Russian:

> [image: site]

As far as I see, the site gets a new build at least once a work day, so there at least were 2 attempts to get new translations from transifex.com. What's the reason why the strings are still not on the site?

Upd: translations are on site now, that took about 7-8 days to be live. Extremely long imho.

Comment: [6 to 8, pays credit to the meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/158100)